# Check if a document set exists

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I'm trying to determine whether a document set exists - if it doesn't I'll send it off to another function to create but I'm not getting the correct value back from my query.

I think it has to do with the document set behaving more like a folder than a list but I'm unsure how I'd go about a similar query to a folder.

```
function checkIfDocSetExists() {
    var docSetExists = false;
    var listItems;

    function checkForDocSet() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
        var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Source Files');
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + thisItemID + "</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>");
        listItems = targetList.getItems(query);
        clientContext.load(listItems);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            console.log("Item found! \nTitle: " + listEnumerator.get_current().get_item("Title"));
        }
        docSetExists = true;
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        console.log('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
        docSetExists = false;
    }
    checkForDocSet();
    (docSetExists == false) ? CreateDocumentSet() : false;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following method to determine whether a document set exists.

### How to find a Document Set via JSOM

```
function getDocSet(listTitle,docSetName, success,error) {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var items = list.getItems(createGetDocSetQuery(docSetName));
    context.load(items);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
         var docSetItem = (items.get_count() > 0 ? items.getItemAtIndex(0) : null);
         success(docSetItem);
      },
      error 
    );


    function createGetDocSetQuery(docSetName)
    {
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        var viewXml =
        "<View>" +
        "<Query>" +
           "<Where>" +
               "<And>" +
                   "<Eq>" +
                      "<FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\"/>" +
                      "<Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value>" +
                   "</Eq>" +
                   "<Eq>" +
                      "<FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\" />" +
                      "<Value Type=\"Text\">" + docSetName + "</Value>" +
                   "</Eq>" +
               "</And>" +
           "</Where>" +
        "</Query>" +
        "<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>" +
        "</View>";
        query.set_viewXml(viewXml);
        return query;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
getDocSet('Documents','Orders',printDocSetInfo,logError);

function printDocSetInfo(item)
{
   if(item == null) {
      console.log('Doc Set not found');
   }   
   else {
      console.log('Doc Set ' + item.get_item('Title') + ' was found');    
   }
}

function logError(sender,args)
{
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. It's a very different approach than I was trying - thanks so much.

Comment: Aaron, glad this helped you :)